# IE10 not working when Opening window and again openning another window

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-10

```
wOpen = window.open( '', newWinName, sOptions);
wOpen.document.write("");
```

This code is not working in IE10.

`wOpen.document.write()` is not working

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Does IE9 reacts fine? does the error happens when your console (F12) is visible?

Comment: Document undefined something 50007 script error

Comment: @user2936008 Do you really need help with this? If you do, please re-read the comments and provide proper information... What has this to do with `pdf`?

Comment: How exactly are you declaring **sOptions**? as Doorknob states, please elaborate your question!

Comment: sOptions I dnt know what it is and Teemu it is in PDF where Link appears

Comment: I found the Answer from my Friend Thanks  Teemu . , I was calling this and showing in PDF . Yes we can show the document.write() in PDF as Link or DATA .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using wOpen.document.write() Please use below line

wOpen.parent.document.write() . Application will be opening new window and PDF will be reported